# How can I Take a photo path from the camera in another activity and send it with volley to the server?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley, android-camera

I write this code and get photo path with intent in my Activity and And I'm showing it correctly on the imageView.

```
class ImageServerActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var bitmap: Bitmap
    val token = "<tokenData>"

    //  var bitmap: Bitmap? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_server)

        btn_server.setOnClickListener {
            uploadImage()
            progressBarSend.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        }


        val path = intent.getStringExtra("path")
        getBitmap(path)
        val image = File(path)

        println("PAthaga :: $path")


    }

    fun getBitmap(path: String?): Bitmap? {

        try {
            val f = File(path)
            val options = BitmapFactory.Options()
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(FileInputStream(f), null, options)!!
            val rotatedBitmap = bitmap?.rotate(90F)

            imgTest.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return bitmap
    }

    fun Bitmap.rotate(degrees: Float): Bitmap {
        val matrix = Matrix().apply { postRotate(degrees) }
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(this, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true)
    }
```

But now I want upload this photo to server with volley but it doesn't work.
My attempt:

```
    private fun uploadImage() {
        val url = "http://application-test.com/api/v1/image"

        val listener = Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> { response ->

            progressBarSend.visibility = View.GONE
            val jsonObject = JSONObject(String(response.data))
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, jsonObject.getString("path"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        }

        val errorListener = Response.ErrorListener { error ->
            progressBarSend.visibility = View.GONE

            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }


        val request = object : VolleyMultipartRequest(Method.PUT, url, listener, errorListener) {


            @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
            override fun getHeaders(): Map<String, String> {
                val params: MutableMap<String, String> =
                    HashMap()
                params["Authorization"] ="Bearer $token"
                params["Accept"] = "application/json"

                return params
            }

            override val byteData: Map<String, DataPart>?
                protected get() {
                    val params: MutableMap<String, DataPart> = HashMap()
                    val imagename = System.currentTimeMillis()
                    params["image"] = DataPart("$imagename.jpg", getFileDataFromDrawable(bitmap))

                    return params
                }
        }

        AppSingleton.getInstance(applicationContext).addToRequestQueue(request)
    }
```

When I use debug I found that this line of code returns me an empty bitmap value and I don't know why:

```
val request = object : VolleyMultipartRequest(Method.PUT, url, listener, errorListener) {


            @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
            override fun getHeaders(): Map<String, String> {
                val params: MutableMap<String, String> =
                    HashMap()
                params["Authorization"] ="Bearer $token"
                params["Accept"] = "application/json"

                return params
            }

            override val byteData: Map<String, DataPart>?
                protected get() {
                    val params: MutableMap<String, DataPart> = HashMap()
                    val imagename = System.currentTimeMillis()
                    params["image"] = DataPart("$imagename.jpg", getFileDataFromDrawable(bitmap)). //bitmap = ""    <-----

                    return params
                }
        }

        AppSingleton.getInstance(applicationContext).addToRequestQueue(request)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check the bitmap url. 
    params["image"] = DataPart("$imagename.jpg", getFileDataFromDrawable(bitmap))
you didnt set the url did you? from where you get the image.

Comment: I get this image from another activity and pass it path of image with intenet ,and with getbitmap() function get bitmap!!
-------------------------------
 
val path = intent.getStringExtra("path")
        getBitmap(path)
        val image = File(path)

        println("PAthaga :: $path")
------------------

I saved that photo in storage can I get that in this line??or I need uri ??how can I get that?I don't understand where I went wrong !!!